# How to Convert CSV to JSON using Python where some JSON keys have multiple values

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert csv to json but couldn't get the expected results

Pyton Code:

```
import csv
import json
  
def csv_to_json(csvFile, jsonFile):    
    jsondict = {}  
    with open(csvFile, encoding='utf_8_sig') as csvfile:  
        csv_data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        jsondict["data"]=[]
        for rows in csv_data:  
            print(rows)
            jsondict["data"].append(rows)
  
    with open(jsonFile, 'w') as jsonfile:  
        jsonfile.write(json.dumps(jsondict, indent = 4))
csvfile = 'sample.csv'  
jsonfile = 'sampleoutput.json'  
  
csv_to_json(csvfile, jsonfile)
```

Sample CSV Data:

| Keys | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | value100-1 |
| 200 | value200-1 |
| 200 | value200-2 |
| 300 | value300-1 |
| 300 | value300-2 |
| 400 | value400-1 |
| 400 | value400-2 |
| 400 | value400-3 |

Expected Result:

```html
    [
      {
        "Keys": "100",
        "Value": "value100-1"
        },
        {
        "Keys": "200",
        "Value": ["value200-1", "value200-2"]
      },
      {
        "Keys": "300",
        "Value": ["value300-1", "value300-2"]
        },
        {
        "Keys": "400",
        "Value": ["value400-1", "value400-2", "value400-3"]
       }
    ]
```

Current Result:

```html
{
    "data": [{
            "Keys": "100",
            "Value": "value100-1"
        },
        {
            "Keys": "200",
            "Value": "value200-1"
        },
        {
            "Keys": "200",
            "Value": "value200-2"
        },
        {
            "Keys": "300",
            "Value": "value300-1"
        },
        {
            "Keys": "300",
            "Value": "value300-2"
        },
        {
            "Keys": "400",
            "Value": "value400-1"
        },
        {
            "Keys": "400",
            "Value": "value400-2"
        },
        {
            "Keys": "400",
            "Value": "value400-3"
        }
    ]
}
```

TIA for you honest and immediate response :)

Comment: Your CSV file starts with a BOM. Remove it when encoding the file, or `open` the file with `encoding='utf_8_sig'`.

Comment: Thank you so much for that
I have modified the code and output in my question
Hope you can help me with my expected result
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to get the expected result…?

Comment: Have tried the code above but not getting the expected result

Comment: @deceze can you reopen the post? I think you misunderstood my question and you close it and flag it as duplicate. the issue is not about BOM.
thanks

Comment: You want to do some grouping and deduplication, which your code is nowhere near even attempting. So… have you tried anything in this regard…?

Comment: Hello @deceze
Just starting to learn python here
haven't done anything about grouping and first time I heard about deduplication
so I only convert csv to json but haven't done anything about what you are asking

Comment: Then please try something and ask us if you're stuck with a specific aspect of it…

Comment: can you reopen this post?
I found the answer now and would like to publish it here :)
thank you for the keyword Grouping and Deduplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above expected result require grouping of data inside csv file
Use code below instead

```
import json
import io
import pandas as pd

raw_string = open("sample.csv", "r")
raw_string = ''.join([i for i in raw_string])  
raw_data = [line.split(',') for line in raw_string.split()]

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw_string))

for item in list(df.groupby(by=[i for i in df.columns if not i.endswith("Value")])):
    df_temp = item[1]
    # messy line that matches columns to their values. The list(set(x) makes it so values are unique but also json serializable
    a = {k : (list(set(v)) if len(set(v)) > 1 else list(set(v))[0]) for k, v in df_temp.to_dict("list").items()}
    print(json.dumps(a, indent=4))
```